# Angular JS-$Http Post not working on chrome/FireFox, but $http.get works fine

Tags: angularjs, http, post, asp.net-web-api

Hi I am trying to POST some data to my WebAPI but, getting error as "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)"

Here is my Angular Call:

```
var req= {
                    url: appSettings.basePath + '/api/Location/PostSearch',
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                    //datatype: 'Json',
                    data: SearchInfo,
                    method: 'POST'
                  }
               return $http(req);
```

My API:

```
public int PostSearch(Search Obj)

{
            Obj.Location = ReplaceDefaultValuesWithBlank(Obj.Location);
            Obj.Sublocation = ReplaceDefaultValuesWithBlank(Obj.Sublocation);
            Obj.PublicationCategory = ReplaceDefaultValuesWithBlank(Obj.PublicationCategory);
            Obj.PublicationName = ReplaceDefaultValuesWithBlank(Obj.PublicationName);
            int IsAdded = Db.USP_SaveSearch(Obj.SSO ?? "", Obj.SearchName ?? "", Obj.Location ?? "", Obj.Sublocation ?? "", Obj.PublicationCategory ?? "", Obj.PublicationName ?? "", Obj.FileNameFilterText ?? "", Obj.Content ?? "", Obj.DateRange ?? "");
            return IsAdded;
        }
```

not sure what is the Problem, Call works fine on IE but doesnt works on Chrome/FireFox,

I dont see any problem with CORS because "GET" works absolutely fine, is this related to custom route that i have introduced in webAPI

WebAPIConfig.cs:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
               name: "DefaultApiWithAction",
               routeTemplate: "Api/{controller}/{action}"
                );

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Pls help me out, I have spent a lot of time troubleshooting still stuck.

Comment: Try getting it, using GET method, you must be confused with some other concept, else everything looks fine, and should work fine with get, you will get results..

Comment: your url should be `url: appSettings.basePath + '/api/Location'`

Comment: Hi, Get methods are seperately defined in my API which are working fine ,but i need this to be working with POST as well because i am trying to post some data which will be stored in my database.Not sure why it doesnt works with POST.

Comment: Gaurav i have added Custom Action routing , i can't append action name as well?

Comment: This error only come when you are expecting data with different method. For example : you have exposed service with get method and request the same api with get method. Please cross check. One more thing let me know the version of angularjs

Comment: Add [HttpPost] on your method

Comment: Hi Le, i tried, still getting this error OPTIONS http://localhost:55166/api/Location/PostSearch (anonymous function)  http://localhost:55166/api/Location/PostSearch. Invalid HTTP status code 405

Comment: Hi,Mohan i have exposed the API method with POST only,

Comment: Angular JS version:1.4.4

Comment: try to add `[Route("")]` attribute on your post method.

Comment: Getting a 405 on the OPTIONS: Deduction-> OPTIONS request ('Preflight') only send for CORS request with POST. High likelyhood this is a CORS problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting a 405 on the OPTIONS: Deduction-> OPTIONS request ('Preflight') only send for CORS request with POST. High likelyhood this is a CORS problem. –  Marvin Smit yesterday

Comment: Thanks Marvin Smit  i used enablecors method and specified third parameter as "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"